# What does the exclamation mark mean in big-o, i.e. O(X!)?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I've seen examples of big-o expressed as `O(X!)` but I am not sure what this means, according to the accompanying charts it is very slow.

Can someone give an example of an `O(X!)` algorithm?

Thanks

Comment: Two answers already given, but just to note - it's not any part of big-o notation as such. Factorial (`!`) is fairly standard mathematical notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means factorial. It is the product of the numbers from 1 to X. So by example, `5! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120`.

Answer (score 2):

! stands for "factorial".

X! is the product of the numbers from 1 to X.